# TOGAF - Does the Architecture Repository contain code?

Tags: togaf

I am trying to understand some of the concepts within TOGAF and was wondering if the Architecture Repository contains source code as well as documentation? I am unsure if TOGAF only relates to documentation or it also relates to physical components?

For example can a Solution Building Block be a physical Microservice with an artefact as a diagram which explains that Microservice and they both exist within the Architecture Repository?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be part of Enterprise Repository as per documentation.

---

Section 37.8 The Enterprise Repository

> These can include development repositories, specific operating environments, instructions, and configuration management repositories.

ref - [Togaf 9.2 documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf9-doc/arch/chap37.html#tag_37_08)

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I would say no; The architecture repository does not contain physical components. It contains specifications (which may in turn refer to physical components in code repositories, but these are outside the architecture repository).

According to the literature from The Open Group, the architecture repository contains catalogs, matrices and diagrams that describe reusable *building blocks* and *architecture deliverables*. The distinction between a *building block* and a *deliverable* here, is that a building block represents a capability that can be combined with other building blocks to deliver architectures and solutions and a deliverable is a is a work product contractually specified, reviewed and formally signed off by stakeholders.

Chapter 29.1 has a nice sketch and definitions: https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf9-doc/arch/chap29.html